# Android switching fragment switches whole view

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity that is half a fragment and half some UI elements .

I want to dynamically switch this fragment programmatically by two other views with their own logic and their own UI but with the UI elements in the first half of the screen and their functionality in common.

my whole problem is when i get to switch fragments using FragmentManager the result is the whole screen is being replaced by the fragment views and overlaps the first half of the activity.

here the code in the activity:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment ();
 SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment ();
 if (mode==2) {
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, secondFragment );

 }else if (mode==1){

 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, firstFragment );
 }
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and here the fragment xml code inside the view of the activity

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

          <fragment    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note i'm not concerned to switch the fragments when the activity is visible, the "mode" variable in my code is set only once at oncreate of the activity.

Could the problem be is that i have to place the first part of the my view that has common UI elements also inside a fragment?

Comment: Can you post the entire xml code for your activity?

Comment: `android.R.id.content` takes the whole view when replacing, you have to give your fragment some id in the layout and use that id in fragmentTransaction

Comment: @doodeec
thank you...that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As doodeec said android.R.id.content gets the whole view, i should have assigned an id to the fragments then call

```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.myfragment, secondFragment );
```

and

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.myfragment, firstFragment );
```